# Convert List comprehension into recursive call

Tags: haskell, recursion, higher-order-functions

```
sieve [] = []
sieve (a:x) = a : sieve [y| y <- x, y `mod` a > 0]
```

I want to convert this code to recursive implementation or using higher order functions such as map and filter. I can't figure out how do I do this.

I have tried this way but it wont seem to work

```
sieve (a:x) = f x : map f xs where f = y `mod` a > 0
```

Comment: you were close: ``sieve (a:xs) = a : filter f xs where {f y = y `mod` a > 0}``.

Answer (score 3):

Is this the kind of thing you want? The list comprehension is only being used to filter the list anyway, so we can convert to a form that manually applies a filter.

```
sieve []     = []
sieve (x:xs) = x : sieve (filter (\y -> y `mod` x > 0) xs)
```

Comment: Note that Chris's answer arises directly from the equivalence of `[y| y <- x, y `mod` a > 0]` with `filter (\y -> y `mod` a > 0) x`. (Markdown's making the backticks a bit wonky.)

Comment: @Chris: Its finding out only the odd numbers and not primes

Comment: @bddesai89: You can implement `filter` by recursion.  Check its definition in the standard library.

Comment: @TomEllis: Its finding out only the odd numbers and not primes

Comment: @bddesai89: looks like you need to fix your algorithm then :)

Comment: @TomEllis If you surround the code with double backticks, you can include backticks in the code. ``y `mod` a``!

Comment: @bddesai89 Oops, my fault - I left out the recursive call to `sieve`.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Chris' fine answer, which boils down to "understand what the code is doing and intuit the correct translation", there is a much more mechanical translation you can do. The behavior of list comprehensions is [specified in the Haskell Report](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-420003.11):

> Translation: List comprehensions satisfy these identities, which may be used as a translation into the kernel:
>
> ```
> [e | True]         =  [e]
> [e | q]            =  [e | q, True]
> [e | b, Q]         =  if b then [e | Q] else []
> [e | p <- l, Q]    =  let ok p = [e | Q]
>                           ok _ = []
>                       in concatMap ok l
> [e | let decls, Q] =  let decls in [e | Q]
> ```
>
> where `e` ranges over expressions, `p` over patterns, `l` over list-valued expressions, `b` over boolean expressions, `decls` over declaration lists, `q` over qualifiers, and `Q` over sequences of qualifiers. `ok` is a fresh variable. The function `concatMap`, and boolean value `True`, are defined in the `Prelude`.

Here's how those rules would apply to your code.

```
[y | y <- x, y `mod` a > 0]
= { fourth equation }
let ok y = [y | y `mod` a > 0]
    ok _ = []
in concatMap ok x
= { second equation }
let ok y = [y | y `mod` a > 0, True]
    ok _ = []
in concatMap ok x
= { third equation }
let ok y = if y `mod` a > 0 then [y | True] else []
    ok _ = []
in concatMap ok x
= { first equation }
let ok y = if y `mod` a > 0 then [y] else []
    ok _ = []
in concatMap ok x
```

After this process, you're left with no list comprehensions. Then we can start applying other transformations we know about; for example, the second clause of `ok` here seems to be dead code, so:

```
= { dead code elimination }
let ok y = if y `mod` a > 0 then [y] else []
in concatMap ok x
= { inlining }
concatMap (\y -> if y `mod` a > 0 then [y] else []) x
```

Whether you can make the intuitive leap from this version of the code to `filter` is of course another question entirely! But it's not necessary to make that leap: this `concatMap` version has no list comprehensions left at all and behaves exactly the same as the original.