# I am struggling to understand how concat is read in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, concatenation, list-comprehension

The code for concat:

```
concat :: [[a]] -> [a]
concat xss = [x | xs <- xss, x <- xs]
```

I don't understand how it is being read. How does `xss` get split into `xs` and `x`? Or am I misreading it?

For example, given:

```
concat [[1,2,3],[4],[5]]
```

how is `[1,2,3,4,5]` achieved?

Comment: Are there any list comprehensions you *do* understand? If yes, perhaps we can draw an analogy with them that will help you; if no, then probably the right next step is to check out one of the many excellent Haskell tutorials and jump to the section on list comprehensions.

Comment: Or, depending on how you are wired, you may find [the Report's section on desugaring](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-420003.11) helpful. I also have an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20414229/791604) giving a worked example of those desugaring rules.

Comment: Hi Daniel. I have just started covering list comprehensions today, but yes, I have understood everything else I have gone over, such as `factors` and `primes`, for instance - it's just `concat` that is confusing. I'll take a read of this two links as soon as I get chance to, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inside a list comprehension, the bit `a <- b` means "*for each `a` in `b`*".

So in your case, `xs <- xss` should read like "*for each `xs` in `xss`*", and then `x <- xs` should read like "*for each `x` in `xs`*", which is also valid becase `xs` itself is a list, because `xss` is a list of lists.

So as the list comprehension unfolds, `xs` becomes bound first to `[1,2,3]`, then to `[4]`, and then to `[5]`, and within each iteration of `xs`, `x` becomes bound to `1`, `2`, `3`, then to `4`, and finally to `5`.

Comment: Ah, this makes sense. What I wasn't seeing was that `xs <- xss` takes the head of the list of list, which is the first list. Then `x <- xs` is the head of that list, etc. Totally makes sense. Thank you, Fyodor :)

Comment: `xs <- xss` *starts* with the head of the list, but it equally takes *every* element of the list.

Answer (score 2):

If we had to make a comparison with imperative programming, we can think of

```
[ expr | x1 <- list1 , x2 <- list2 , ....]
```

as a nested for loop accumulating the values resulting from `expr` in a list, as follows:

```
result = []
for x1 in list1:
  for x2 in list2:
    ...
    result.append(expr)
```

In you case, we have

```
result = []
for xs in xss:
  for x in xs:
    result.append(x)
```

So, when `xss = [[1,2,3],[4],[5]]` we have:

- `xs = [1,2,3]`

  - `x = 1` gets appended to the result
  - `x = 2` gets appended to the result
  - `x = 3` gets appended to the result
- `xs = [4]`

  - `x = 4` gets appended to the result
- `xs = [5]`

  - `x = 5` gets appended to the result

The final result is therefore `[1,2,3,4,5]`.

This comparison is not a completely faithful description, since it does not take laziness into account, and Haskell does not really compute the final list by appending data to a mutable list as done above. Perhaps Python's `yield` and generators would be closer. Still, the comparison above should illustrate the basic mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Well with the obvious identities,

```
[ E | P <- (xs ++ ys), Q ]  ===  [ E | P <- xs, Q ] ++ [ E | P <- ys, Q ]

[ x | xs <- [E], x <- xs ]  ===  [ x | x <- E ]

[ x | x <- [E] ]  ===  [E]
```

we can just follow the code,

```
concat        [[1,2,3],     [4], [5]]
 = {- by definition of `concat` -}
   [x | xs <- [[1,2,3],     [4], [5]], x <- xs]
 = {- by definition of `++`     -}
   [x | xs <- [[1,2,3]] ++ [[4], [5]], x <- xs]
 = {- by the first identity     -}
   [x | xs <- [[1,2,3]], x <- xs] ++ [x | xs <- [[4], [5]],  x <- xs]
 = {- by the second identity    -}
   [x | x <-   [1,2,3]          ] ++ [x | xs <- [[4], [5]],  x <- xs]
 = {- by definition of `++`     -}
   [x | x <-   [1,2,3]          ] ++ [x | xs <- [[4]] ++ [[5]], x <- xs]
 = {- by the first identity     -}
   [x | x <-   [1,2,3]] ++ [x | xs <- [[4]], x <- xs] ++ [x | xs <- [[5]], x <- xs]
 = {- by the second identity    -}
   [x | x <-   [1,2,3]] ++ [x | x <-   [4]          ] ++ [x | x <-   [5]          ]
 = {- and by the third          -}
   [x | x <-   [1,2,3]] ++ [            4           ] ++ [            5           ]
 = {- repeating as before       -}
   [x | x <- [1]] ++ [x | x <- [2]] ++ [x | x <- [3]] ++ [4] ++ [     5           ]
 = {- by the third identity     -}
   [          1 ] ++ [          2 ] ++ [          3 ] ++ [4] ++ [     5           ]
 = {- by definition of `++`     -}
   [          1   ,             2   ,             3   ,   4  ,        5           ]
```

Thus `concat`, when applied to a list of lists, has the effect of "opening up" and eliminating the inner parentheses in it.

In the process we have also discovered another identity,

```
[ x | x <- Q ]  ===  Q
```

which follows from the ones above and the properties of `++`, where

```
[A,B,C,...,Z]  ===  [A] ++ [B] ++ [C] ++ ... ++ [Z]
```

See also:

- [An introduction to the theory of lists](https://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/files/3378/PRG56.pdf). Technical Monograph PRG-56, R.S. Bird 1986.